# Ignore zeros (or blanks) in Excel LINEST function with multiple independent variables

Tags: excel, regression, linear-regression, missing-data

I would like to run a multiple (!) factor analysis through linest, again excluding all rows that contain zeros (or if that’s easier blank cells). Is there a way I can do this using the linest functions?

I tried using the following formular, which I have found somewhere else, but would not get anything but #VALUE!.

```
=LINEST(IF(ISNUMBER(C15:C26);C15:C26;);IF(ISNUMBER(C15:C26);CHOOSE({1;2;3};1;D15:D26;E15:E26););1;1)
```

FYI – Y values are is column C, and my X values in column D & E.

Thanks in advance!
Julian

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J77eT.png)

Comment: I have also found the below linest/offset function, which allows me to exclude cells - however, I only managed to make it work for a single regression *****                                                                       =LINEST(OFFSET(C15;MATCH(1;I15:I26;0)-1;0;SUM(I15:I26);1);OFFSET(D15;MATCH(1;I15:I26;0)-1;0;SUM(I15:I26);1);0;1)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this has been solved yet but ive been trying to do this myself and found a solution. we can now use the FILTER function. if the range is C15:C26, the following should work

```
=LINEST(FILTER(C15:C26,C15:C26<>0,))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest that you filter your data to exclude any row containing zeros or blank cells in any of the columns, and then copy the filtered data to another area of your worksheet or a separate worksheet altogether.  Then you can simply use `LINEST`.

Otherwise, you can use the following formula that needs to be confirmed with `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER`...

```
=LINEST(INDEX(C:C,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(MMULT(--(C15:E26=0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C15:E26))^0)=0,ROW(C15:E26)*{1,1}))))),INDEX(D:E,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(MMULT(--(C15:E26=0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C15:E26))^0)=0,ROW(C15:E26)*{1,1})))),N(IF(1,{1,2}))),1,1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the empty cells with my function **discard_empty** . The function transfers a range to values without empty values and LINEST works.

```
=LINEST(discard_empty(A1:A9))

Function discard_empty(range_in As Range)
Dim arr_temp() As Variant
Dim arr_new() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
    arr_temp = range_in
    For k = LBound(arr_temp, 1) To UBound(arr_temp, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr_temp, 2) To UBound(arr_temp, 2)
            ReDim Preserve arr_new(i)
            arr_new(i) = arr_temp(k, j)
            i = i + 1
        Next j
    Next k
    arr_temp = arr_new
    Erase arr_new
    j = 0
    For k = LBound(arr_temp) To UBound(arr_temp)
       If arr_temp(k) <> Empty Then
            ReDim Preserve arr_new(j)
            arr_new(j) = arr_temp(k)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next k
    discard_empty = arr_new
End Function
```